# Visual studio 2019 Test is failing with error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, xunit

I had recently upgraded to Visual studio 2019 from 2017. The tests (xunit) was working fantastic until this update. But after updating, when i run my tests it just says "Outcomes Not Run".!!! strange, even it doesn't shows any details of any error under Output window, later found we have to manually change
 "Show output from: " drop-down in Output window to "Tests" to see that. I got these details as below

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710016): Unable to start program C:\Users\bb00001\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\16.5.0\build\netcoreapp2.1\x64\testhost.exe.

This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
```

Since I works in a very restrictive environment, understood i cant run any exes under that location since GP restriction. But got access to particular locations under C Drive.

Is there anyway I can change my testhost.exe file location? which visual studio can pickup the exe from a configured path?

Comment: Did you try running VS as Admin?

Comment: The error code is *access denied*, and the reason that it's denied is a group policy. There's nothing you can do about that, becasue the GP will need to be changed to fix the issue. Did you try contacting your network admins to get their help resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After referring the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders,
I had set an environmental variable like below, where i set a new nuget-package source which my group policy allows me to run applications

[image]

This will automatically override the default location to newly setup location. Later restart the visual studio and rebuild the solution, it must add all the dependencies to new location. It worked for me. Not sure this issue will occur to anyone else, but maybe helpful, if someone with need.